# Adding linear layout messes up the layout in preview (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

After positioning everything in the layout. When I add a LinearLayout all the positions of the components get messed up. And I can't even position them back. If I move them they move back to the messed up position.
How do I get them back into the positions I had given earlier? Thank You

Here are before and after:

[image: This image of preview is before adding]

[image: This image of preview is after adding]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="@string/title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:text="@string/date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/NasaImageView"
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_height="345dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you could do

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="@string/title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:text="@string/date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/NasaImageView"
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_height="345dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `android:gravity` to center in linerLayout and add margin to the child.

Comment: I got the components in the center but still can't position them in the places I want.

Comment: Thank You it helped.